# Insert into temp table using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, temp-tables

I want to create a temp table from a result of CTE using SQLAlchemy.

Tables definition:

```
class Data(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'data'
  c_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  # ...

# temp table
class CIdTmp(Base):
  __tablename__ = '#c_id_tmp'
  c_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

This is my CTE:

```
c_id_cte = (session.query(Data.c_id)).cte('c_id_cte')
```

I tried combining `insert()` with `from_select()` like this:

```
session.execute(CIdTmp.insert().from_select(['c_id'], c_id_cte))
```

But it produces this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'CIdTmp' has no attribute 'insert'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out that I have to get a `Table` object to execute an `insert` expression. It can be done by using `___table__` on my model.

```
session.execute(CIdTmp.__table__.insert().from_select(['c_id'], c_id_cte))
```